# eZpublish contact form (collection)

Tags: php, ezpublish

Our eZpublish 4.3 contact form is randomly sending emails to the ezpublish site admin email address instead of the correct form address.

The contact form is a standard 'information collection' ezpublish form, the user choose from a select box a department to contact then type his/her message and hit send.

The site is running on a Debian 7 box with PHP 5.6 installed via apt-get (as an apache module). eZpublish 4.3 need PHP 5.3 so we have compiled a PHP 5.3 from source and put it in `/opt/php53` and it's run with php-fpm.

Sometimes the email is sent to the correct department email address, but sometimes it is sent to the site admin address.

My question is how can I debug what is going on? I can't find anything in apache logs. I tried looking in ezpublish log file but can't find anything of value there either.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Check the code that sends the email (share it if possible so that we can help you). Also, make sure that the email addresses are validated server side and not sent as a hidden param in your form, otherwise the user would be able to change it with the console.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something wrong with one of the values of your selectbox. Replicate in development and use xdebug or other debugging technique to show the Post values in form PHP controller. If those are wrong then your template or content is probably wrong.
Edit 2 :  look at the HTML to check select values instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchy for email_receiver is like this:

```
membership_coordinator_email_address
```

attribute in your feedbackform class if its not set, mail will send to:

> ...\settings\siteaccess\YOUR_SITE_NAME\site.ini.append.php

```
[InformationCollectionSettings]EmailReceiver=example@mail.com
```

if its not set, mail will send to:

> ...\settings\override\site.ini.append.php

```
[MailSettings]AdminEmail=admin_example@mail.com
```

For more information check tutorial on official site (maybe you messed something with ur feedbackform): http://share.ez.no/learn/ez-publish/how-to-create-ez-publish-forms